# Rails activerecord with all or where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I can't see the difference in the ruby console between Model.all and Model.where(:source_id => 2). My problem is with the «all» instruction I can do .each on the array and with Model.where I can't do .each

Working

```
# controller.rb
@results = Adress.all

#view.haml
- @results.each do |result|
```

Not-Working

```
# controller.rb
@results = Adress.where(:source_id => 2)

#view.haml
- @results.each do |result|
```

Error message --> undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

In console    --> Adress.where(:source_id => 2) it's works

------- MY BAD, THE SOLUTION ------

my view was trying to do .each on inexistent variable.......

THE PROBLEM

```
@Adress = Adress.where(:arrondissement_id => params[:arrondissement])
```

THE SOLUTION

```
@results = Adress.where(:arrondissement_id => params[:arrondissement])
```

Comment: What does `Adress.where(:source_id => 2)` return in Rails console?

Comment: HASH ==>  [#<Adress id: 2, arrondissement_id: 2, nom: "Centre récréatif Mgr-Bouffard", adresse: "680, Rue Raoul-Jobin, Québec (QC) G1N 4N1 ", telephone: nil, siteinternet: nil, description: nil, vues: 120, id_album_photo: nil>, #<Adress id: 7, arrondissement_id: 2, nom: "Y.W.C.A", adresse: "855, Av Holland, Québec (QC) G1S 3S5 ", telephone: nil, siteinternet: nil, description: nil, vues: 0, id_album_photo: nil>]

Comment: Is it the actual code in your controller? Because `Model#all` and `Model#where` both return an Array, while your second view seems to be getting `nil` instead of an array.

Comment: Ahhh.... I think it's time to go to the bed. I give the wrong name to my variable. Thank you :)

Comment: Also, I know it's hard to remember for us French folks, but "Address" takes two Ds in English ("Adresse" takes one D in French). Watch for the typos, it might give you errors! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad,

my view was trying to do .each on inexisting.

THE PROBLEM

```
@Adress = Adress.where(:arrondissement_id => params[:arrondissement])
```

THE SOLUTION

```
@results = Adress.where(:arrondissement_id => params[:arrondissement])
```